# Simple bash shell script to ensure that provides two arguments

Tags: bash, shell, scripting

I'm trying to write simple greetings script in bash to ensure that the user provides at least two arguments. 1)The first argument provides how long we want to delay before the greeting prints. 2) The second argument provides what message we want to display. Sorry I'm fairly new to shell scripting.

```
#!/bin/sh
if[$# -ge 2]
then
   sleep $1
   shift
   banner $*
else
   echo "Usage: Greeing seconds word(s)"
fi
```

Comment: [shellcheck.net](http://shellcheck.net) is a great tool for catching syntax errors in shell code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should use:

```
#!/bin/sh
if [ $# -ge 2 ]
then
    sleep $1
    shift
    banner $*
else
    echo "Usage: Greeing seconds word(s)"
fi
```

You were missing:

- a space after `if`
- a space around `[` and `]`

Answer (score 3):

If you want to ensure that 2 arguments are given, use `${2?}`.  For example:

```
echo First arg is ${1?Missing first argument}.  2nd arg is ${2?Missing 2nd argument}
```